# Disable time ranges in jquery timepicker dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, time

```
var eachTime = "11.00 am,11.15 am,11.30 am,11.45 am,11.45 am,12.00 pm,12:00  pm,12.15 pm,12:15  pm,12.30 pm";
```

How to make an array whose value is `['11.00 am','11.15 am'],['11.30 am','11.45 am'], ...,['12:15  pm','12.30 pm']`
I need to make such array to pass to `timepicker` for disabling this time.
Any one please help me

Comment: You want to convert first string to that array?

Comment: yes, how can i convet it to array as ['11.00 am','11.15 am'],['11.30 am','11.45 am'], ...,['12:15  pm','12.30 pm']

Comment: you have doubled items in the string `12.00 pm,12:00  pm,12.15 pm,12:15  pm,`

Answer (score 1):

Though there's a doubled items in your string, I can suggest the solution for converting  the string into array of consecutive "time" pairs(used functions: `String.split`, `Array.forEach` and `Array.push`):

```
var eachTime = "11.00 am,11.15 am,11.30 am,11.45 am,11.45 am,12.00 pm,12:00  pm,12.15 pm,12:15  pm,12.30 pm",
    time_arr = eachTime.split(","), new_arr = [];

time_arr.forEach(function(v, k , arr){
    if (k % 2 & 1) new_arr.push([arr[k-1], arr[k]]);  // check for odd keys
})

console.log(JSON.stringify(new_arr, 0, 4));
```

The output:

```
[
    [
        "11.00 am",
        "11.15 am"
    ],
    [
        "11.30 am",
        "11.45 am"
    ],
    [
        "11.45 am",
        "12.00 pm"
    ],
    [
        "12:00  pm",
        "12.15 pm"
    ],
    [
        "12:15  pm",
        "12.30 pm"
    ]
]
```

[demo link](https://jsfiddle.net/ms1cw6dw/)

Comment: Provide demo to seeing online result instead of writing `output`.

Comment: the output is not so bad. Besides, not as "instead", added demo link

Comment: Ok, it work properly but why you used `JSON.stringify()` in code?

Comment: check documentation for `JSON.stringify()` with additional params and you will understand. Without it, the output would not be such beautiful/readable